# Как сделать,чтобы при нажатии на ImageView  открывался сайт?

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать,что бы при нажатии на ImageView  открывался сайт?

Предположительно  так( возмжено бред, ибо только начинаю изучение).
Буду очень благодарен за подсказки,помощь.

```
mImageView1 = (imageView)findViewById(R.id.info);
mImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           и дальше что делать без понятия.
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте эту ссылку: [Пишем простой браузер](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/72-urok-32-pishem-prostoj-brauzer.html). Там не `imageView`, но как вызывать браузер написано

Answer (score 1):

Непонятна суть вопроса. Вы хотите сделать просмотр сайта через внешний браузер или через свой? Второй вариант уже описал [@aleksandr_mai](/users/20599/aleksandr_mai), а первый опишу я.

```
mImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mIntent.setData(Uri.parse("сайт, который надо открыть"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser("Выберите браузер", mIntent));
    }
});
```

Comment: Достаточно просто:

     startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://")) )

В таком случае система автоматически предложит сформированный на основе данных интента список приложений( активностей ), способных обработать действие.